# Linux: How can I get a different exit code from the find command if no files matching the pattern I used are found?

Tags: bash, find

I have a script which runs the next command:

```
find /storage2/hpfiles_staging/ -name \*.gz -mmin +600
```

And then `rsync`'s the files to a remote location.

Sometimes the `find` command returns no output (as there are no files named *.gz with age of 10 minutes or more in that location).
When it happens, I want to write a message to the log saying there are no files there.

But when I run the `find` command, whether it finds files to transfer or not the exit code of the `find` command is always "0" (unless there's a syntax error of course) and thus cannot give me indication about files being found in that location or not.

Is there any switch or a trick to get a different exit code than 0 if no files have been found by the `find` command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just thought about something... I could check using `wc -l` how many lines of output were received from the find command...

Comment: Just save the output to a variable and check if it's empty.  I'll link to an existing question here that shows you how to do that next.

Comment: I found an elegant way of doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71375403/522104

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can affect the exit code from find. You should perhaps look to capture the output from find and use that to determine if any files where found.